# pgrouting - pgr_nodeNetwork: Can NOT determine the srid of the geometry "osm_id" IN table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, srid

I have been following the guide in order to import PBF data into a PostGIS database: [pgrouting - documentation](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgRouting-concepts.html#getting-started).
I have downloaded the Belgium PBF from Geofabrik and installed all extensions needed into my database.

Then I have successfully completed the `pgr_createTopology`, `pgr_analyzegraph` and `pgr_analyzeoneway` steps in the documentation.

The next step is to the `pgr_nodeNetwork` function onto the table in order to check if the data is noded correctly. But when executing this step onto my table I keep on getting an error. I execute the function `select pgr_nodeNetwork('planet_osm_line', 0.001, 'way', 'osm_id');` with also declaring both the `geom` and the `id` column names. The problem isn't solved when I rename both columns to the default names used by the `pgr_nodeNetwork` function.

```
NOTICE:  PROCESSING:
NOTICE:  id: way
NOTICE:  the_geom: osm_id
NOTICE:  table_ending: noded
NOTICE:  rows_where: 
NOTICE:  outall: f
NOTICE:  pgr_nodeNetwork('planet_osm_line', 0.001, 'way', 'osm_id', 'noded', '',  f)
NOTICE:  Performing checks, please wait .....
NOTICE:  ERROR: Can NOT determine the srid of the geometry "osm_id" IN table public.planet_osm_line
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the hints from the function output and compare with the [docs](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgr_nodeNetwork.html) carefully; the function signature is defined as *[emphasis mine; slightly reduced to lessen confusion]*:

> pgr_nodenetwork(edge_table, tolerance, **id**, **the_geom**, table_ending, rows_where, outall)
> RETURNS TEXT

and your progress messages read

```
[...]
NOTICE:  id: way
NOTICE:  the_geom: osm_id
[...]
```

You want to pass in the `id` column **before** the geometry column:

```
SELECT pgr_nodeNetwork('planet_osm_line', 0.001, 'osm_id', 'way');
```

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! I did not notice it because in all the previous functions it was the other way around.